# Problem to install Apache 2.4.2 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I followed these steps to install Apache 2.4.2 in Ubuntu 12.04, but it seems Apache is not installed, here's what I did (I followed the steps on this site http://www.discusswire.com/apache-2-4-installation-ubuntu/):

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep apache2
wget http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/httpd/httpd-2.4.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf httpd-2.4.2.tar.gz && cd httpd-2.4.2
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-deflate --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-proxy-http --with-mpm=prefork
sudo make
sudo make install
```

when I tried to start by issuing `sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start` at terminal, I got the following warning:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message" and when I typed **top** at terminal, the apache is not there. I also tried to go to <CODE>http://localhost/</CODE> or 127.0.0.1 or even 127.0.1.1 it showed "Can't establish connection to server ..." message.
```

P.S.: I checked the error log and it showed

```
[Fri Jul 27 15:49:00.703901 2012] [proxy_balancer:emerg] [pid 20781] AH01177: Failed to lookup provider 'shm' for 'slotmem': is mod_slotmem_shm loaded??
[Fri Jul 27 15:49:00.704083 2012] [:emerg] [pid 20781] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in 2.4 (it does in 2.2). but the command "httpd -M" will show all of the modules that are loaded in apache.  Is mod_slotmem_shm loaded?

Comment: See the question below to install the latest version

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/308461/install-apache-php-mysql-latest-versions-not-available-via-apt][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/308461/install-apache-php-mysql-latest-versions-not-available-via-apt

Comment: Just a remark, but you should never run `./configure` and `make` with `sudo`, only `make install`.

Answer (score 7):

found this as a bug with httpd and it has not been fixed for long now. The fix was as mentioned in error i.e. you need to uncomment the following line in httpd.conf:

```
#LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
```

to

```
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the ServerName message is relevant.  You should be able to clear that up by specifying a servername with the ServerName directive in apache's main config file.

Have you checked apache's error logs?  They may show something

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ppa:rhardy/apache24x](https://launchpad.net/~rhardy/+archive/apache24x) repository for apache 2.4.2 installation in ubuntu 12.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rhardy/apache24x
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
ServerName yourhostname
```

or just copy this line and paste in your terminal and execute:

```
sudo sh -c "echo \"ServerName $( hostname )\" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
```

it'll do the job for you instead of manually editing your apache2.conf.

Secondly, this line will fix the module issue:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_slotmem_shm.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_slotmem_shm.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```